# how to make package for my python project

Tags: python

I have a python project, which uses qt(UI) for user input and then creates the pdf using latex.
I want to make full package of my whole projects in some form of exe.

I came to know about pyinstaller, pyexe and cx_frezer.
So which one should I pick up first.
My exe should run in windows 98, xp, vista and linux. 
So how does MiKTeX ( windows) and qt get bundle to my exe.
Does I have to make different exe depending upon the operation system.

Any link for reading will be nice.

Comment: Try `py2exe`, but I'm not sure that you can get one package to work on all OSes. http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: An excellent discussion on py2exe and Linux http://wiki.python.org/moin/Py2Exe

Answer (score 0):

This might be a viable alternative to freeze and py2exe. Python allows compilation into bytecode. You will have to do this on all of your target platforms for specific python versions. Run in root of your project folder

> python -m compileall

*See http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html for details.*

After that, delete all *.py files leaving only *.pyc. Note that such compilations must work up to a specific three digits' version of python's runtime, so this is not very convenient.